# VS2015 ConnectedServicesPackage package did not load correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015

After installing VS2015 update 3 and the VS Core package, now every time I open a solution, I am prompted with a message that states that the ConnectedServicesPackage did not load correctly.

Looking in the ActivityLog.xml, I see that it's looking for:
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices.Package2.dll

I have no idea where to get this dll, or what package it was a part of.  Anyone know how to solve this problem, where to get this dll, or what package this dll is a part of?

Thanks!